# Errors with 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I'm having a problem with the this pointer inside of a custom class.  My code looks as follows.

```
class Foo{
   public:  void bar();  bool baz();
};

bool Foo::baz(){
   return true;
}
void Foo::bar(){
   bool is_baz = (*this).baz();
}
```

As I said above, I believe the error I'm getting (LNK2019) is coming from the this.  I think it is looking for a function in a different file, which it does not find.  Is there some way I can make this code work, or do I have to use some sort of work-around?  If so, what should I do to work around this problem.  Thank you.

Comment: Why do you not just call `baz()`?  What is the exact error emitted by the linker?

Comment: Not all C++ compilers use the same error numbers. Either name the compiler or give the text of the error message. I'd guess at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z(v=vs.80).aspx but it's only a guess.

Comment: You want to tell us what LNK2019 is?  What line does it refer to? What symbols are mentioned?  Or you want us to debug with ESP?

Comment: Unrelated stylistic hint: `this->baz()` is a little easier on the eyes (and fingers) than `(*this).baz()`.  Even better, as James McNellis points out, is just `baz()`, without the qualifying `this`.  C++ automatically resolves names within a class.

Comment: @Silvae: The code you posted will fail to compile with syntax errors. It will not produce LNK2019 (assuming MSVC++ compiler). This means that you posted fake code. Post real code, please.

Comment: @Silvae: Also, LNK2019 is usually caused by splitting source code across several source files incorrectly. Which means that you have to show us how you split it. In any case, the error has absolutely nothing to do with `this` pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Foo(){
```

Change this to

```
class Foo{
```

Also, this shouldn’t compile. How did you manage to get a link error?

After making this change, the linker says `undefined reference to 'main'`, which just means you don't have a `main` function.

Comment: Yes, this strongly suggests that the code snippet is not the actual code but a garbled rewritten version, which will make it very difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not an error, the line

```
bool is_baz = (*this).baz();
```

does not need the `(*this)` part. It can be written simply as

```
bool is_baz = baz();
```

But, what's the point of computing `is_baz` if it is neither used nor returned?